# How to let Pool.map take a lambda function

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I have the following function:

```
def copy_file(source_file, target_dir):
    pass
```

Now I would like to use `multiprocessing` to execute this function at once:

```
p = Pool(12)
p.map(lambda x: copy_file(x,target_dir), file_list)
```

The problem is, lambda's can't be pickled, so this fails. What is the most neat (pythonic) way to fix this?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Use a function object:

```
class Copier(object):
    def __init__(self, tgtdir):
        self.target_dir = tgtdir
    def __call__(self, src):
        copy_file(src, self.target_dir)
```

To run your `Pool.map`:

```
p.map(Copier(target_dir), file_list)
```

Comment: What if `copy_file` were `self.copy_file` in a method?

Answer (score 71):

[For Python2.7+](http://bugs.python.org/issue5228) or Python3, you could use [functools.partial](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
import functools
copier = functools.partial(copy_file, target_dir=target_dir)
p.map(copier, file_list)
```

Comment: This one even looks cleaner... I will decide later which one to make my answer

Comment: @Peter Smit: Oops -- you saw my post before I deleted it... I'm undeleting this just to announce it doesn't work due to a bug in Python2.

Comment: Ah, ok. I was looking in the docs and didn't see a comment about the pickability, so I assumed they were... I'll accept the other answer then, as that seems to be the way to go.

Comment: Still, a +1 for this answer since it's shorter (in Python 3, that is ;)

Comment: Landing here much later, as an update `functools.partial` is also picklable in python 2.7.

Comment: This solution has the problem that only  the second and higher arguments can be "curried". The function object solution is much more flexible.

Comment: Used this to fix a parallel search for non-isomorphic graphs. It runs 15x faster than the Fred Foo's solution

Answer (score 11):

Question is a bit old but if you are still use Python 2 my answer can be useful.

Trick is to use part of [pathos](https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos) project: [multiprocess](https://github.com/uqfoundation/multiprocess) fork of multiprocessing. It get rid of annoying limitation of original multiprocess.

Installation: `pip install multiprocess`

Usage:

```
>>> from multiprocess import Pool
>>> p = Pool(4)
>>> print p.map(lambda x: (lambda y:y**2)(x) + x, xrange(10))
[0, 2, 6, 12, 20, 30, 42, 56, 72, 90]
```

Answer (score 1):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816958/cant-pickle-type-instancemethod-when-using-pythons-multiprocessing-pool-ma?noredirect=1&lq=1) answer, pathos let's you run your lambda `p.map(lambda x: copy_file(x,target_dir), file_list)` directly, saving all the workarounds / hacks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `starmap()` to solve this problem with pooling.

Given that you have a list of files, say in your working directory, and you have a location you would like to copy those files to, then you can `import os` and use `os.system()` to run terminal commands in python. This will allow you to move the files over with ease.

However, before you start you will need to create a variable `res = [(file, target_dir) for file in file_list]` that will house each file with the target directory.

It will look like...

```
[('test1.pdf', '/home/mcurie/files/pdfs/'), ('test2.pdf', '/home/mcurie/files/pdfs/'), ('test3.pdf', '/home/mcurie/files/pdfs/'), ('test4.pdf', '/home/mcurie/files/pdfs/')]
```

Obviously, for this use case you can simplify this process by storing each file and target directory in one string to begin with, but that would reduce the insight of using this method.

The idea is that `starmap()` is going to take each component of `res` and place it into the function `copy_file(source_file, target_dir)` and execute them synchronously (this is limited by the core quantity of your cpu).

Therefore, the *first* operational thread will look like

`copy_file('test1.pdf', '/home/mcurie/files/pdfs/')`

I hope this helps. The full code is below.

```
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool
import os

file_list = ["test1.pdf", "test2.pdf", "test3.pdf", "test4.pdf"]
target_dir = "/home/mcurie/files/pdfs/"


def copy_file(source_file, target_dir):
    os.system(f"cp {source_file} {target_dir + source_file}")
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool() as p:
        res = [(file, target_dir) for file in file_list]
        for results in p.starmap(copy_file, res):
            pass
```