# How can I thread my remote MongoDB calls?

Tags: python, mongodb, python-multithreading

So I have a few machines on the network running MongoDB:

- I can easily write code to connect to one from my PC and return a result set, e.g.:

> ```
> from pymongo import Connection
> c = Connection("10.130.10.12")
> some_data = c.MyData.MyCollection.find_one()
> ```

- If I have, say 100 servers to connect to, and want to put this in a loop, that's easy too:

> ```
> all_data = []
> for server in my_list_of_servers:
>     c = Connection(server)
>     all_data.append(c.MyData.MyCollection.find_one())
> ```

- However this does it one-by-one and could be quite slow.
- How can I send out all the requests at once? I'm super unfamiliar with threading (is that what I should even be looking into?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def connectAndCollect(server):
    c = Connection(server)
    return c.MyData.MyCollection.find_one()

pool = Pool(processes=10)
res = pool.map(connectAndCollect,servers)
map(lambda x: all_data.append(x),res)
pool.close()
```

The multiprocessing library is designed for this sort of task.  The final `map` call can be replaced by a for loop if you like.

A description of using the multiprocessing module for Map/Reduce tasks in general is described here:
http://mikecvet.wordpress.com/2010/07/02/parallel-mapreduce-in-python/

Comment: Thanks! But pool.map can't accept this function? PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.func                             tion failed

Comment: **EDIT**

Because I am foolish, I suggested something impossible:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827432/how-to-let-pool-map-take-a-lambda-function

Don't use lambdas in `pool.map`.  This final accumulation step won't really benefit from the multiprocessing anyway.

Comment: woo! It works ^_^ 
What is `res` short for though? 
Also, I'm more familiar with list comprehensions than maps - could this line: `map(lambda x: all_data.append(x),res)` be replaced this list comprehension: `all_data.append([x for x in res])` . Are they equivalent in function/memory? (sorry! so many questions )

Comment: `res` is just a generic result variable.  The list comprehension will not work in this case, because instead of appending each item, you will append the list itself.  If you want a list comprehension, you can try `all_data.extend([x for x in res])` - just make sure everything is initialized properly and check things with test cases first.