# Python, use multiprocessing to further speed up a cython function

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multiprocessing, cython

the code shown here are simplied but triggers the same PicklingError. I know there is a lot discussion on what can and cannot be pickled, but I did find the solution from them.

I write a simple cython script with the following function:

```
def pow2(int a) : 
    return a**2
```

The compilation is working, I can call this function in python script.

[image]

However, I am wondering how to use this function with multiprocessing,

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from fast import pow2
p = Pool(processes =4 )
y = p.map( pow2, np.arange( 10, dtype=int))
```

gives me an PicklingError: 
[image]

dtw is the name of the package, and fast is fast.pyx.

How can I get around this problem? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: turns out I need to simply wrap around the cython function. If you have similar problem, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827432/how-to-let-pool-map-take-a-lambda-function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using `multiprocessing`, which implies writting data on disk due to the pickling process you can use the OpenMP wrapper `prange`. In your case you could use it like shown below.

- note the use of `x*x` instead of `x**2`, avoiding the function call `pow(x, 2)`):
- a part of the array is passed to each thread, using `double` pointers
- the last thread takes more values when `size % num_threads != 0`

Code:

```
#cython: wraparound=False
#cython: boundscheck=False
#cython: cdivision=True
#cython: nonecheck=False
#cython: profile=False
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
from cython.parallel import prange

cdef void cpow2(int size, double *inp, double *out) nogil:
    cdef int i
    for i in range(size):
        out[i] = inp[i]*inp[i]

def pow2(np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] inp,
         np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] out,
         int num_threads=4):
    cdef int thread
    cdef np.ndarray[np.int32_t, ndim=1] sub_sizes, pos
    size = np.shape(inp)[0]
    sub_sizes = np.zeros(num_threads, np.int32) + size//num_threads
    pos = np.zeros(num_threads, np.int32)
    sub_sizes[num_threads-1] += size % num_threads
    pos[1:] = np.cumsum(sub_sizes)[:num_threads-1]
    for thread in prange(num_threads, nogil=True, chunksize=1,
                         num_threads=num_threads, schedule='static'):
        cpow2(sub_sizes[thread], &inp[pos[thread]], &out[pos[thread]])

def main():
    a = np.arange(642312323).astype(np.float64)
    pow2(a, out=a, num_threads=4)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I tried that. prange doesn't work for me, because I use numpy style slicing in the loop, which creates a python object, the GIL has to be applied. My input is actually a list of unequal length vectors, and I put them in a big numpy 2d array filled with zeros for missing values. and the second input is a int array that indicates the length of each vector in the first parameter. Is there a better way ? Thanks

Comment: @fasttooth, but the input you described should be no problem.... when you put them in the big `2d-array` you can use the pointers as well, but in this case the pointer will be `&a[row, col]`...

Comment: isn't &a[row, col] points the address of the (row, col) element ? Do i have to write a C-like loop to copy out from the 2d array to a local c-array?

Comment: @fasttooth `&a[row, col]` will give the address of an element, which is what you need, when you do `double *b; b = &a[row, col]`, `b` is a `double` buffer starting at element `(row, col)`, such that `b[0]==a[row, col]`; and `b[1]==a[row, col+1]` for `C` memory layout or `b[1]==a[row+1, col]` for `Fortran` memory layout