# Reducing computation Time for a nested Loop

Tags: python, performance, loops, optimization, parallel-processing

I would like to reduce the computation time for the code posted below. In essence, the code below calculates the array `Tf` as product of the following nested loop:

```
Af = lambda x: Approximationf(f, x)
for idxp, prior in enumerate(grid_prior):
    for idxy, y in enumerate(grid_y):
        posterior = lambda yPrime: updated_posterior(prior, y, yPrime)
        integrateL = integrate(lambda z: Af(np.array([y*np.exp(mu[0])*z,
                                            posterior(y*np.exp(mu[0]) * z)])))
        integrateH = integrate(lambda z: Af(np.array([y*np.exp(mu[1])*z,
                                            posterior(y * np.exp(mu[1])*z)])))
        Tf[idxy, idxp] = (h[idxy, idxp] +
                          beta * ((prior * integrateL) +
                                  (1-prior)*integrateH))
```

The objects `posterior`, `integrate` and `Af` are functions that are repeatedly called while iterating over the loop. The function `posterior` calculates a scalar called `posterior`. The function `Af` approximates the function `f` at sample points `x` and passes the result on to the function `integrate`, which calculates the conditional expectation of the function `f`.

The code posted below is a simplification of a more difficult problem. Instead of running the nested loop once, I have to run it multiple times to solve a fixed point problem. This problem is initialized with an arbitrary function `f` and a function `Tf` is created. This array is then used in the next iteration over the nested loop to calculate another array `Tf`. The process continues until convergence.

I decided not to report results of the `cProfile` module. By neglecting the iteration over the nested loop until convergence a lot of internal python executions require a relatively long time. However, when iterating until convergence, these internal executions loose their relative importance and are relegated to lower positions in the `cPython` output.

I tried to mimick different suggestions for lowering the computation time of loops I found online for slightly modified problems. Unfortunately, I couldn't do so and could not really figure out a common approach to tackle these problems. Does somebody has an idea how to lower the computation time of this loop? I am grateful for any help!

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
from scipy.stats import lognorm
from scipy.integrate import fixed_quad

# == The following lines define the paramters for the problem == #
gamma, beta, sigma, mu = 2, 0.95,  0.0255, np.array([0.0113, -0.0016])
grid_y, grid_prior = np.linspace(7, 10, 15), np.linspace(0, 1, 5)
int_min, int_max = np.exp(- 7 * sigma), np.exp(+ 7 * sigma)
phi = lognorm(sigma)

f = np.array([[ 1.29824564,  1.29161017,  1.28379398,  1.2676886, 1.15320819],
[ 1.26290108, 1.26147364,  1.24755837,  1.23819851,  1.11912802],
[ 1.22847276,  1.23013194,  1.22128198,  1.20996971, 1.0864706 ],
[ 1.19528104,  1.19645792,  1.19056084,  1.17980572, 1.05532966],
[ 1.16344832,  1.16279841,  1.15997191,  1.15169942,  1.02564429],
[ 1.13301675,  1.13109952,  1.12883038,  1.1236645,  0.99730795],
[ 1.10398195,  1.10125013,  1.0988554,   1.09612933,  0.97019688],
[ 1.07630046,  1.07356297,  1.07126087,  1.06878758,  0.94417658],
[ 1.04989686,  1.04728542,  1.04514962,  1.04289665,  0.91910765],
[ 1.02467087,  1.0221532,   1.02011384,  1.01797238,  0.89485162],
[ 1.00050447,  0.99795025,  0.99576917,  0.99330549,  0.87127677],
[ 0.97726849,  0.97443288,  0.97190614,  0.96861352, 0.84826362],
[ 0.95482612,  0.94783816,  0.94340077,  0.93753641,  0.82569922],
[ 0.93302433,  0.91985497,  0.9059118,   0.88895196,  0.80348449],
[ 0.91165997,  0.88253486,  0.86126688,  0.84769975,  0.78147382]])

# == Calculate function h, Used in the loop below ==  #
E0 = np.exp((1-gamma)*mu + (1-gamma)**2*sigma**2/2)
h = np.outer(beta*grid_y**(1-gamma), grid_prior*E0[0] + (1-grid_prior)*E0[1])

def integrate(g):
    """
    This function is repeatedly called in the loop below
    """
    integrand = lambda z: g(z) * phi.pdf(z)
    result = fixed_quad(integrand, int_min, int_max, n=15)[0]
    return result

def Approximationf(f, x):
    """
    This function approximates the function f and is repeatedly called in
    the loop
    """
        # == simplify notation == #
    fApprox = np.empty((x.shape[1]))
    lower, middle = (x[0] < grid_y[0]), (x[0] >= grid_y[0]) & (x[0] <= grid_y[-1])
    upper = (x[0] > grid_y[-1])

    # = Calculate Polynomial == #
    y_tile = np.tile(grid_y, len(grid_prior))
    prior_repeat = np.repeat(grid_prior, len(grid_y))
    s = interpolate.SmoothBivariateSpline(y_tile, prior_repeat,
                                          f.T.flatten(), kx=5, ky=5)

    # == interpolation == #
    fApprox[middle] = s(x[0, middle], x[1, middle])[:, 0]

    # == Extrapolation == #
    if any(lower):
        s0 = s(lower[lower]*grid_y[0], x[1, lower])[:, 0]
        s1 = s(lower[lower]*grid_y[1], x[1, lower])[:, 0]
        slope_lower = (s0 - s1)/(grid_y[0] - grid_y[1])
        fApprox[lower] = s0 + slope_lower*(x[0, lower] - grid_y[0])
    if any(upper):
        sM1 = s(upper[upper]*grid_y[-1], x[1, upper])[:, 0]
        sM2 = s(upper[upper]*grid_y[-2], x[1, upper])[:, 0]
        slope_upper = (sM1 - sM2)/(grid_y[-1] - grid_y[-2])
        fApprox[upper] = sM1 + slope_upper*(x[0, upper] - grid_y[-1])
    return fApprox

def updated_posterior(prior, y, yPrime):
    """
    This function calculates the posterior weights put on each distribution.
    It is the thrid function repeatedly called in the loop below.
    """
    z_0 = yPrime/(y * np.exp(mu[0]))
    z_1 = yPrime/(y * np.exp(mu[1]))
    l0, l1 = phi.pdf(z_0), phi.pdf(z_1)
    posterior = l0*prior / (l0*prior + l1*(1-prior))
    return posterior

Tf = np.empty_like(f)
Af = lambda x: Approximationf(f, x)
# == Apply the T operator to f == #
for idxp, prior in enumerate(grid_prior):
    for idxy, y in enumerate(grid_y):
        posterior = lambda yPrime: updated_posterior(prior, y, yPrime)
        integrateL = integrate(lambda z: Af(np.array([y*np.exp(mu[0])*z,
                                            posterior(y*np.exp(mu[0]) * z)])))
        integrateH = integrate(lambda z: Af(np.array([y*np.exp(mu[1])*z,
                                            posterior(y * np.exp(mu[1])*z)])))
        Tf[idxy, idxp] = (h[idxy, idxp] +
                          beta * ((prior * integrateL) +
                                  (1-prior)*integrateH))
```

**Some experience with multiprocessing** Following  **reptilicus** comment, I decided to investigate how to use the multiprocessing module. My idea was to  begin by parallizing the computation of the `intergrateL` array. To do so, I fixed the outer loop to `prior =0.5` and wanted to iterate over the inner loop, `grid_y`. However, I still have to take into consideration that `intergrateL` is a `lambda` function in `z`. I tried to follow the advice of the stack-overflow question "[How to let Pool.map take a lambda function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827432/how-to-let-pool-map-take-a-lambda-function)" and wrote the following code:

```
prior = 0.5
Af = lambda x: Approximationf(f, x)

class Iteration(object):
    def __init__(self,state):
        self.y = state
    def __call__(self,z):
        Af(np.array([self.y*np.exp(mu[0])*z, 
                    updated_posterior(prior,
                                      self.y,self.y*np.exp(mu[0])*z)]))

with Pool(processes=4) as pool:
    out = pool.map(Iteration(y), np.nditer(grid_y))
```

Unfortunately, python returns upon running the program:

```
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

On first sight, these sniffs like a trivial error, but I cannot remedy it. Does somebody has an idea how to tackle the problem? Again, I'm grateful for  any advice I receive!

Comment: You could try to write that nested for loop in Cython, but I don't know how much speedup you will get because it looks like most of the calcs are done in numpy and should be close to C speed already. You could use `multiprocess` to split the calculation into several chunks then create the output when all are finished.

Comment: Or if you are feeling real frisky, could set up several machines on ec2 and use zeromq to distribute the calcs to multiple machines.

Comment: @reptilicus  Thank you very much for your reply! Could you maybe kindly give me a hint as how to use multiprocess?

Comment: Also, not sure if its possible just looking at the code, but could look into vectorizing the `integrate` function. See http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html

Comment: Here's a link to `multiprocessing` https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers

Comment: @reptilicus I tried to exploit your comment about multiprocessing, however did not manage to go the full way. I described my problem at the end of the question above. Do you have an idea how to tackle the problem?

Comment: I think I would go another route and parallelize the nested loop, so that each (idxp, prior), (idxy, y) pair was calculated seperately (and in parallel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would target that nested loop, something like this. This is psuedo-code but it should get you started.

```
def do_calc(idxp, idxy, y, prior):
    posterior = lambda yPrime: updated_posterior(prior, y, yPrime)
    integrateL = integrate(lambda z: Af(np.array([y*np.exp(mu[0])*z,
                                            posterior(y*np.exp(mu[0]) * z)])))
    integrateH = integrate(lambda z: Af(np.array([y*np.exp(mu[1])*z,
                                            posterior(y * np.exp(mu[1])*z)])))

    return (idxp, idyy, posterior, integrateL, integrateH)

pool = multiprocessing.pool(8) # or however many cores you have
results = []
# This is the part that I would try to parallelize 
for idxp, prior in enumerate(grid_prior):
    for idxy, y in enumerate(grid_y):
        results.append(pool.apply_async(do_calc, args=(idxpy, idxy,  y, prior))
pool.close()
pool.join()
results = [r.get() for r in results]
for r in results:
    Tf[r[0], r[1] = (h[r[0], r[1]] +
                          beta * ((prior * r[3]) +
                                  (1-prior)*r[4))
```

Comment: Dear reptilicus: Thank you for your reply. I implemented your idea (and slightly edited your post), it works. I will profile the resulting program and report time savings later today.

Comment: Cool, yeah let me know if it did speed things up!

Comment: Dear reptilicus: Thank you for your reply! Your suggestions worked very well and helped me a lot in getting started with my problem.

Comment: Great! What kind of speedup did you get (if any)?

Comment: Dear reptilicus: Well, the speedup was about 5-10%. I suspect that the gins can be increased in my original application. As I wrote above, I iterate over the nested loops until convergence. I therefore work in an object oriented environment but I cannot apply the code above to the problem because some a `lambda` expression cannot be pickled. I learned that there are different ways to tackle it but I couldn't get the gist of the way to do things yet. I'm thinking of asking another question to address this issue.

Comment: Well thats not much of an improvement. Have you gotten anything better since?