# Python multiprocessing - How to create a function that parallelizes a for loop

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, jupyter-notebook, python-multiprocessing

If you open a Jupyter Notebook and run this:

```
import multiprocessing
def f(x):
    a = 3 * x
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=1)
    global g
    def g(j):
        return a * j
    return pool.map(g, range(5))
f(1)
```

You will get the following errors

```
Process ForkPoolWorker-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/process.py", line 249, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/Users/me/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/me/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 108, in worker
    task = get()
  File "/Users/me/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 345, in get
    return ForkingPickler.loads(res)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'g' on <module '__main__'>
```

and I'm trying to understand if this is a bug or a feature.

I'm trying to get this working because in my real case `f` is basically a for loop easily parallelizable (you only change one parameter each iteration) but that takes a lot of time on each iteration! Am I approaching the problem correctly or is there an easier way? (Note: Throughout the notebook f will be called several times with different parameters itself)

Answer (score 2):

It works just fine if you define `g` outside of `f`.

```
import multiprocessing

def g(j):
    return 4 * j

def f():
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=1)
    return pool.map(g, range(5))

f()
```

**Edit**:
In example you put in your question callable object will look somewhat like this:

```
class Calculator():
    def __init__(self, j):
        self.j = j

    def __call__(self, x):
        return self.j*x
```

and your function `f` becomes something like this:

```
def f(j):
    calculator = Calculator(j) 
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=1)
    return pool.map(calculator, range(5))
```

I in this case it works just fine. Hope it helped.

Comment: But the problem is that `g` uses variable values that are computed in the body of `f` so it cannot be defined outside! See my edited question reflecting this situation

Comment: In this case: I believe this one will help 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827432/how-to-let-pool-map-take-a-lambda-function

Comment: I don't get it! I don't even understand if this means that this is a bug or a feature?

Comment: `multiprocessing.pool` uses `pickle` to pass arguments. Module level functions are picklable but lambdas and local functions are not, so you can't pass lambda functions. If you create custom object it is picklable so you can pass it. It's more of a bug than a feature but it's by design so you have to accept it.

Comment: I understand.. But how do I do it in my case? I am clueless on how to create a function object that will solve this problem

Comment: Updated my answer with example for you particular case.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply `g` to more arguments than only the iterator element passed by `pool.map` you can use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) like this:

```
import multiprocessing
import functools

def g(a, j):
    return a * j

def f(x):
    a = 3 * x
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=1)
    g_with_a = functools.partial(g, a)
    return pool.map(g_with_a, range(5))

f(1)
```

What `functools.partial` does, is to take a function and an arbitrary number of arguments (both by position and keyword) and returns a new function that behaves like the function you passed to it, but only takes the arguments you didn't pass to `partial`.

The function returned by `partial` can be pickled without problems i. e. passed to `pool.map`, as long as you're using python3.

This is essentially the same as Darth Kotik described in his answer, but you don't have to implement the `Calculator` class yourself, as `partial` already does what you want.