# Save sklearn cross validation object

Tags: python, machine-learning

Following the tutorial for [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html), I attempted to save an object that was created via sklearn but was unsuccessful. It appears the problem is with the cross validation object, as I can save the actual (final) model.

Given:

```
rf_model = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=1000, n_jobs=4, compute_importances = False)
cvgridsrch = GridSearchCV(estimator=rf_model, param_grid=parameters,n_jobs=4) 
cvgridsrch.fit(X,y)
```

This will succeed:

```
joblib.dump(cvgridsrch.best_estimator_, 'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\DMA\\cvgridsrch.pkl', compress=9)
```

and this will fail:

```
joblib.dump(cvgridsrch, 'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\DMA\\cvgridsrch.pkl', compress=9)
```

with error:

```
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'instancemethod'>: it's not found as __builtin__.instancemethod
```

How to save the full object?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Python 2,
try:

```
import dill
```

So that lambda functions can be pickled....

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause could be multithreading issue, which you may refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816958/cant-pickle-type-instancemethod-when-using-pythons-multiprocessing-pool-ma) stackoverflow answer.

Also, is it possible for you to dump your object not via joblib but a more fundamental method like pickle (and not even cPickle, which is more restrictive)?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but it might be useful for people coming here having the same, or similar, problem.

I'm not sure of the specific error message, but I managed to sucessfully save the entire GridSearchCV object in my own project by using pickle:

```
import pickle
gs = GridSearchCV(some parameters) #create the gridsearch object
gs.fit(X, y) # fit the model
with open('file_name', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(gs, f) # save the object to a file
```

Then you can use

```
with open('file_name', 'rb') as f:
    gs = pickle.load(f)
```

to read the file and hence be able to use the object again.