# Python: AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'writeBuf.<locals>.write'

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I am not at all familiar with Python, I usually do Ruby or JS. But I need to write a benchmarking script on a system that runs Python. What I'm trying to do is create a small script that gets a file size and the number of threads and write a random buffer. This is what I got after 2 hours of fiddling:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import os, sys

def writeBuf(buf):
    def write(n):
        f = open(os.path.join(directory, 'n' + str(n)), 'w')
        try:
            f.write(buf)
            f.flush()
            os.fsync(f.fileno)
        finally:
            f.close()
    return write

if __name__ == '__main__':
    targetDir = sys.argv[1]
    numThreads = int(sys.argv[2])
    numKiloBytes = int(sys.argv[3])
    numFiles = int(102400 / numKiloBytes)

    buf = os.urandom(numKiloBytes * 1024)

    directory = os.path.join(targetDir, str(numKiloBytes) + 'k')
    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        os.makedirs(directory)

    with Pool(processes=numThreads) as pool:
        pool.map(writeBuf(buf), range(numFiles))
```

But it throws the error: `AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'writeBuf.<locals>.write'`

I have tried before to use `write` without the closure, but I got an error when I tried to define the function inside the `__name__ == '__main__'` part. Omitting that `if` also lead to an error and I read that it is required for `Pool` to work.

What's supposed to be just a tiny script turned into a huge ordeal, can anyone point me the right way?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In theory, python can't pickle functions. (for details, see [Can't pickle Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22157954/cant-pickle-function))

In practice, python pickles a function's name and module so that passing a function will work. In your case though, the function that you're trying to pass is a local variable returned by `writeBuf`.

Instead:

1. Remove the `writeBuf` wrapper.
2. Don't use the `write` function's closure (`buf` and `directory`), instead give `write` everything it needs as a parameter.

Result:

```
def write(args):
    directory, buf, n = args

    with open(os.path.join(directory, 'n' + str(n)), 'w') as f:
        # might as well use with-statements ;)
        f.write(buf)
        f.flush()
        os.fsync(f.fileno)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ...

    with Pool(processes=numThreads) as pool:
        nargs = [(directory, buf, n) for n in range(numFiles)]
        pool.map(write, nargs)
```