# how can i use multiprocessing.Pool.map in python for function in objects?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

i'm trying to use multiprocessing.Pool to parallelize an operation on a set of class objects.

```
obj= []
for i in range(20):
    obj.append(myClass(i))
pool= multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
pool.map(do_something, obj)
pool.map(do_something_else, obj)
```

and myClass and its function do_something and do_something_else are like this..

```
class myClass:
    def __init__(self,i):
        self.obj_id= i
        self.value= 0

    def do_something():
        self.value = self.value + 1   #some operations

    def do_something_else():
        self.value = self.value * 99   #some operations
```

How can i do this parallelization? and will the 'value' of the original objects in obj get updated? Can anyone help me with a solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't pickle <type 'instancemethod'> when using python's multiprocessing Pool.map()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816958/cant-pickle-type-instancemethod-when-using-pythons-multiprocessing-pool-ma)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `map` function does not call methods on a list of objects, but a function with each object as first argument.

Therefore you need a helper function:

```
def _call_do_something(obj):
    obj.do_something ()
    return obj

# ...
obj_list = pool.map(_call_do_something, obj_list)
```

Since this will spawn a new process that needs to find `_call_do_something` via import (at least on Windows), make it a module-level function.

Comment: This won't work, as the object state won't be transferred back to the main process. At the main process the value of `obj.value` will still be 0

Comment: i tried the same thing with a helper function. But i got an error saying "TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
". may be its a problem with the iterable. and as @justhalf mentioned, obj.value won't be updated.

Comment: No, you'll get a new object with an updated value. Your error is caused because somewhere you are passing an integer where a sequence is expected, like `len(42)` or `map(func, 23)`. The traceback tells you where.

Comment: ok, i rectified my error. But, still the obj.value won't be updated. Oh, i didn't see that reassignment to obj_list. Cool. Using that return and reassignment, one can get the updated obj. Worked for me..Thank you @ferdinand