# Parallelizing a python function that takes a dict as input

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have the following function:

```
class BulkRemoteiTunesUpdater():

    def __init__(self):
        ...
    def run_update(self, update_dict):
        # do something
```

I want to parallelize this process. So far I have:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    b=BulkRemoteiTunesUpdater()
    b.fetch_updates_to_do_info()

    fetched_update_info = b.fetched_update_info
    pool = Pool(NUM_IN_PARALLEL)
    pool.map(b.run_update, fetched_update_info)
    pool.join()
```

What I have above raises the following error:

```
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'instancemethod'>: 
    attribute lookup __builtin__.instancemethod failed
```

What am I doing wrong here? And how would I correctly parallelize this?

Comment: What is BulkRemoteiTunesUpdater / fetched_update_info?

Comment: fetched_update_info returns to me a list of dict objects that I need for my function `run_update`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816958/cant-pickle-type-instancemethod-when-using-pythons-multiprocessing-pool-ma), the problem is that your iterable instancemethod `fetched_update_info` is not picklable. You'll have to go through the hassle of making it so to parralelize it.

OR, if you can get a list out of the iterable first, you may be able to avoid this, such as:

```
pulled = []
for obj in b.fetched_updated_info():
    pulled.append(obj)

pool.map(b.run_update, pulled)
```

Answer (score 0):

two small changes:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    b=BulkRemoteiTunesUpdater()
    b.fetch_updates_to_do_info() # a list of dicts

    pool = Pool(NUM_IN_PARALLEL)
    pool.map(b.run_update, b.fetched_update_info()) # fetch data
    # not needed: pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Here's a full example of how to use `Pool.map`:

### source

```
import multiprocessing

def calc(num):
    return num*2

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(5)
for output in pool.map(calc, [1,2,3]):
    print 'output:',output
```

### output

```
output: 2
output: 4
output: 6
```

Comment: This `b.fetched_update_info()` now returns the Error `list object is not callable`.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by extracting the instance methods and converting them into normal functions. Then when I called the function I didn't get the pickle errors.