# Multiprocessing Python with RPYC "ValueError: pickling is disabled"

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, rpyc

I am trying to use the multiprocessing package within an `rpyc` service, but get `ValueError: pickling is disabled` when I try to call the exposed function from the client. I understand that the `multiprocesing` package uses pickling to pass information between processes and that pickling is not allowed in `rpyc` because it is an insecure protocol. So I am unsure what the best way (or if there is anyway) to use multiprocessing with rpyc. How can I make use of multiprocessing within a rpyc service? Here is the server side code:

```
import rpyc
from multiprocessing import Pool

class MyService(rpyc.Service):

    def exposed_RemotePool(self, function, arglist):

        pool = Pool(processes = 8)
        result = pool.map(function, arglist)
        pool.close()
        return result


if __name__ == "__main__":
    from rpyc.utils.server import ThreadedServer
    t = ThreadedServer(MyService, port = 18861)
    t.start()
```

And here is the client side code that produces the error:

```
import rpyc

def square(x):
    return x*x

c = rpyc.connect("localhost", 18861)
result = c.root.exposed_RemotePool(square, [1,2,3,4])
print(result)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816958/cant-pickle-type-instancemethod-when-using-pythons-multiprocessing-pool-ma?rq=1

Comment: The object can ordinarily be pickled (it's just an integer), but rpyc forbids pickling and thus (seemingly) multiprocessing which uses pickling. I am not implementing a new protocol, I am trying to use rpyc. If it cannot be done I will look for other solutions but I would rather not reinvent the wheel. And if it cannot be done I am at a loss for why rpyc exists, i.e. what's the point of using another machine if you can only make use of one processor on that multi-core machine.

Comment: there are many reasons for multithreading not easily done in a network env.   one of them is that CPU assignment is done inside the kernel, and userspace thread library can only request to use this facility - but not always guaranteed.   And well said is this:   http://intermediate-and-advanced-software-carpentry.readthedocs.org/en/latest/multiprocessing.html  (that GIL makes multithreaded as fast as single threaded, and that "global" lock is within a single host).

Comment: Try setting in rpyc's config `allow_pickle=True`.

Comment: @shx2 it's unclear how to pass that setting to the service (see comment on answer below).

Comment: Btw, this also happens when using copy.deepcopy() which also uses pickle in its implementation, not just with multiprocessing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can enable pickling in the protocol configuration. The configuration is stored as a dictionary, you can modify the [default](http://rpyc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/core_protocol.html#rpyc.core.protocol.DEFAULT_CONFIG) and pass it to both the server (`protocol_config` = ) and client (`config =`). You also need to define the function being parallelized on both the client and server side. So here is the full code for `server.py`:

```
import rpyc
from multiprocessing import Pool
rpyc.core.protocol.DEFAULT_CONFIG['allow_pickle'] = True

def square(x):
    return x*x


class MyService(rpyc.Service):

    def exposed_RemotePool(self, function, arglist):

        pool = Pool(processes = 8)
        result = pool.map(function, arglist)
        pool.close()
        return result



if __name__ == "__main__":
    from rpyc.utils.server import ThreadedServer
    t = ThreadedServer(MyService, port = 18861, protocol_config = rpyc.core.protocol.DEFAULT_CONFIG)
    t.start()
```

And for `client.py` the code is:

```
import rpyc

rpyc.core.protocol.DEFAULT_CONFIG['allow_pickle'] = True

def square(x):
    return x*x

c = rpyc.connect("localhost", port = 18861, config = rpyc.core.protocol.DEFAULT_CONFIG)
result = c.root.exposed_RemotePool(square, [1,2,3,4])
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should enable it in the protocol configuration. See http://rpyc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/core_protocol.html#rpyc.core.protocol.DEFAULT_CONFIG

Comment: I added `rpyc.core.protocol.DEFAULT_CONFIG['allow_pickle'] = True` to my code at the top, but I am still getting the error. Unsure how to change this setting for the ThreadedServer object.