# Python Multiprocessing: process.start works but pool.apply_async gives pickle 'instancemethod' error

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, pickle

I would like to know in what scenarios python's `multiprocessing` libary would give the `Can't pickle <type 'instancemethod'>` error when using the `pool.apply_async`, **but not when using the `process.start` method**. If I understood correctly, the `process.start` method should also be pickling the code, so not much should differ in terms of requirements, or am I mistaken?

Here is the general structure of the code I am having this issue with (the actual functions are too long and complex to condense accurately):

```
import multiprocessing as mult

def f2(name):
    print 'hello' + name

def f1(x):
    return str(x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #This works fine
    processes = []
    for x in xrange(100):
        name = f1(x)
        p = mult.Process(target=f2, args=(name,))
        processes.append(p)
    for p in processes:
        p.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #This gives the pickle error
    pool = mult.Pool() 
    for x in xrange(100,200):
        name = f1(x)
        pool.apply_async(f2, args=(name,))
    pool.close()
```

Note: the completed processes do not need to join with the main process after completing. Also, I am running this on Win7 64 with a 64bit version of Python.

I hope this question is different enough from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816958/cant-pickle-type-instancemethod-when-using-pythons-multiprocessing-pool-ma).

Comment: Are you on Windows? I'm on Ubuntu and get no error.

Comment: @ReutSharabani - Yes I am.

Comment: @ReutSharabani - You wouldn't get an error with this specific code, I presume that the actual f1 and f2 functions (not the one in the snippet) are the cause of the error.

Comment: Well, I can't help you without knowing what you're trying to pickle. Where are the actual methods defined? In the global scope of the module?

Here is a list of what can be pickled:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled

Comment: I'm starting to think that the method I'm running is simply impossible to pickle (too long to check), but this doesn't explain why `process.start` works. Does process.start not need to pickle the method?

Comment: My guess is that the call to `Process` defines the data in the spawning process and then `fork`s. The call to `Pool`, on the other hand, `fork`s some processes and then defines the data (which is not available on the spawned processes later...)

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27318290/why-can-i-invoke-a-multiprocessing-process-with-an-instance-method-as-the-target/27320254#27320254) for the reason for this and a solution.

Comment: Thanks @dano - this is an excellent answer. A bit frustrating that no one answered when I posted this question. Also, not that it really matters, but technically-speaking, the one you are referring to is the duplicate.

Comment: @TimY I think the issue was that your question didn't have any code that could be used to reproduce the problem,so it wasn't completely clear what issue you were hitting. And yes, I did realize the other question was technically the dupe, but I had already written my answer there before I noticed this one in the related items tab. Had I saw it before I would have put the answer here.

Comment: That's a good point. No problem. In any case, many thanks for linking!