# Spark returning Pickle error: cannot lookup attribute

Tags: python, apache-spark, pickle

I am running some attribute lookup problems when trying to initiate a class within my RDD.

my workflow:

1- Start with an RDD

2- Take each element of the RDD, initiate an object for each

3- Reduce (I will write a method that will define the reduce operation later on)

Here is #2:

```
>class test(object):
def __init__(self, a,b):
    self.total = a + b

>a = sc.parallelize([(True,False),(False,False)])
>a.map(lambda (x,y): test(x,y))
```

Here is the error I get:

> PicklingError: Can't pickle < class '**main**.test' >: attribute lookup **main**.test failed

I'd like to know if there is any way around it. Please, answer with a working example to achieve the intended results (i.e. creating a RDD of objects of class "tests").

Related questions:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/edx-code/9xzRJFyQwnI
- [Can't pickle <type 'instancemethod'> when using python's multiprocessing Pool.map()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816958/cant-pickle-type-instancemethod-when-using-pythons-multiprocessing-pool-ma)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From Davies Liu (DataBricks):

"Currently, PySpark can not support pickle a class object in current
script ( '**main**'), the workaround could be put the implementation
of the class into a separate module, then use "bin/spark-submit
--py-files xxx.py" in deploy it.

in xxx.py:

```
class test(object):
     def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.total = a + b
```

in job.py:

```
from xxx import test
a = sc.parallelize([(True,False),(False,False)])
a.map(lambda (x,y): test(x,y))
```

run it by:

```
bin/spark-submit --py-files xxx.py job.py
```

"

Just want to point out that you can pass the same argument (--py-files) in the Spark Shell too.

Comment: If 'spark` swaps out `cloudpickle` for `dill`, you could do this. https://spark-project.atlassian.net/browse/SPARK-791

Comment: I was already surprised after reading 'pickle will serialize almost any Python object' and then getting this error.

Comment: How can you pass the same argument in the spark shell?

Comment: sounds like pyspark is not very well mature