# Python multiprocessing in objects

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing, consumer, producer

I'm writing a program where a variable number of Agent objects concurrently run a number of serial methods and store their return values in a queue attribute.  Each Agent has as an attribute a single Worker (subclass of Process) and feeds it jobs to run serially through a cmd_queue.  The Agent gets the results from its Worker in a res_queue.  These are currently Manager().Queue() instances and cause:
`TypeError: Pickling an AuthenticationString object is disallowed for security reasons`  However, if I used a regular Queue.Queue, the Workers get a copy of the Agent's cmd_queue and cannot see what the Agent adds to it (it's always empty).

I'm able to pickle instance methods with the solution referenced in this question : [Can't pickle <type 'instancemethod'> when using python's multiprocessing Pool.map()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816958/cant-pickle-type-instancemethod-when-using-pythons-multiprocessing-pool-ma)

```
from multiprocessing import Manager, Process
from time import sleep
import copy_reg  

def _pickle_method(method):
    func_name = method.im_func.__name__
    obj = method.im_self
    cls = method.im_class
    return _unpickle_method, (func_name, obj, cls)

def _unpickle_method(func_name, obj, cls):
    for cls in cls.mro():
        try:
            func = cls.__dict__[func_name]
        except KeyError:
            pass
        else:
            break
    return func.__get__(obj, cls)

copy_reg.pickle(types.MethodType, _pickle_method, _unpickle_method  

class Worker(Process):
    def __init__(self, cmd_queue, res_queue):
        self.cmd_queue = cmd_queue
        self.res_queue = res_queue
        Process.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            f, args, kwargs = self.cmd_queue.get()
            self.res_queue.put( f(*args, **kwargs) )  

class Agent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cmd_queue = Manager().Queue()
        self.res_queue = Manager().Queue()
        self.worker = Worker(self.cmd_queue, self.res_queue)
        self.worker.start()

    def produce(self, f, *args, **kwargs):
        self.cmd_queue.put((f, args, kwargs))

    def do_some_work(self):
        self.produce(self.foo, waka='waka')

    def do_some_other_work(self):
        self.produce(self.bar, humana='humana')

    def foo(self, **kwargs):
        sleep(5)
        return('this is a foo')

    def bar(self, **kwargs):
        sleep(10)
        return('this is a bar')

    def get_results(self):  #blocking call
        res = []
        while not self.cmd_queue.empty():#wait for Worker to finish
            sleep(.5)
        while not self.res_queue.empty():
            res.append(self.res_queue.get())
        return res  

#This is the interface I'm looking for.
if __name__=='__main__':
    agents = [Agent() for i in range(50)]
    #this should flow quickly as the calls are added to cmd_queues
    for agent in agents:        
        agent.do_some_work()
        agent.do_some_other_work()  
    for agent in agents:
        print(agent.get_results())
```

My question is, how I would be able to get this code to work using multiprocessing or is there a better, more accepted method of getting this pattern to work?  This is a smaller part of a larger framework so I'd like it to be as OO friendly as possible.

Edit: This is in python 2.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using an ordinary `multiprocessing.Queue`. You just need to tweak the `Agent` class so that it doesn't try to pickle the `Queue` instances when the `Agent` class itself is pickled. This is required because you have to pickle the `Agent` instance itself when you pickle the instance methods you're sending to `Worker`. It's easy enough to do this, though:

```
class Agent(object): # Agent is now a new-style class
    def __init__(self):
        self.cmd_queue = Queue()
        self.res_queue = Queue()
        self.worker = Worker(self.cmd_queue, self.res_queue)
        self.worker.start()

    def __getstate__(self):
        """ This is called to pickle the instance """
        self_dict = self.__dict__.copy()
        del self_dict['cmd_queue']
        del self_dict['res_queue']
        del self_dict['worker']
        return self_dict

    def __setstate__(self, self_dict):
        """ This is called to unpickle the instance. """
        self.__dict__ = self_dict

    ... # The rest is the same.
```

Note that there are some other logic issues in this code that keeps it from running properly; `get_results` doesn't really do what you expect it to do, because this is susceptible to race conditions:

```
    while not self.cmd_queue.empty():#wait for Worker to finish
        sleep(.5)
    while not self.res_queue.empty():
        res.append(self.res_queue.get())
```

`cmd_queue` could (and does, with your example code) end up being empty before the functions you've actually passed to it are done running inside `Worker`, which will mean some of your results will be missing when you pull everything out of `res_queue`. You can fix that by using a [`JoinableQueue`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.JoinableQueue), which allows the workers to actually signal when they're done.

You should also send a sentinel to the worker processes so that they shut down properly, and so that all their results get flushed from `res_queue` and sent back to the parent properly. I also found I needed to add a sentinel to `res_queue`, otherwise sometimes `res_queue` would show up as empty in the parent before the last result written to it from a child actually got flushed across the pipe, meaning the last result would get lost.

Here's a complete working example:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, JoinableQueue
import types
from time import sleep
import copy_reg  

def _pickle_method(method):
    func_name = method.im_func.__name__
    obj = method.im_self
    cls = method.im_class
    return _unpickle_method, (func_name, obj, cls)

def _unpickle_method(func_name, obj, cls):
    for cls in cls.mro():
        try:
            func = cls.__dict__[func_name]
        except KeyError:
            pass
        else:
            break
    return func.__get__(obj, cls)

copy_reg.pickle(types.MethodType, _pickle_method, _unpickle_method)

class Worker(Process):
    def __init__(self, cmd_queue, res_queue):
        self.cmd_queue = cmd_queue
        self.res_queue = res_queue
        Process.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        for f, args, kwargs in iter(self.cmd_queue.get, 
                                    (None, (), {})): # None is our sentinel
            self.res_queue.put( f(*args, **kwargs) )  
            self.cmd_queue.task_done() # Mark the task as done.
        self.res_queue.put(None) # Send this to indicate no more results are coming
        self.cmd_queue.task_done() # Mark the task as done

class Agent(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cmd_queue = JoinableQueue()
        self.res_queue = Queue()
        self.worker = Worker(self.cmd_queue, self.res_queue)
        self.worker.start()

    def __getstate__(self):
        self_dict = self.__dict__.copy()
        del self_dict['cmd_queue']
        del self_dict['res_queue']
        del self_dict['worker']
        return self_dict

    def __setstate__(self, self_dict):
        self.__dict__ = self_dict

    def produce(self, f, *args, **kwargs):
        self.cmd_queue.put((f, args, kwargs))

    def do_some_work(self):
        self.produce(self.foo, waka='waka')

    def do_some_other_work(self):
        self.produce(self.bar, humana='humana')

    def send_sentinel(self):
        self.produce(None)

    def foo(self, **kwargs):
        sleep(2)
        return('this is a foo')

    def bar(self, **kwargs):
        sleep(4)
        return('this is a bar')

    def get_results(self):  #blocking call
        res = []
        self.cmd_queue.join() # This will block until task_done has been called for every put pushed into the queue.
        for out in iter(self.res_queue.get, None):  # None is our sentinel
            res.append(out)
        return res  

#This is the interface I'm looking for.
if __name__=='__main__':
    agents = [Agent() for i in range(50)]
    #this should flow quickly as the calls are added to cmd_queues
    for agent in agents:        
        agent.do_some_work()
        agent.do_some_other_work()  
        agent.send_sentinel()
    for agent in agents:
        print(agent.get_results())
```

Output:

```
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
```

Comment: This is also a nice solution.  It does involve some of the requisite head-standing to get `multiprocessing` to work...  I might suggest, to make life a little simpler and replace 16 lines (from `import copy_reg` to `copy_reg.pickle(…)`) with one line: `import dill`.  That one line registers `type.Method`, and is the same as your 16 lines.  It adds a dependency outside of the standard library, but unless you are an absolute purist, that shouldn't matter…

Comment: Thank you, this is huge.  I was able to get it running earlier by using some global dictionaries whose keys are uuids for each Agent/Worker pair and whose values were Manager.Queues (along with one with an Event for the race condition you mentioned) but it was a little wonky.  This is **the** answer for all relevant SO questions imo.

Comment: Why did you set `self.daemon = True` in Worker?  Is that a robustness thing to allow it create processes in the future or was it necessary for your solution?

Comment: @PrckPgn Actually, that shouldn't be there at all. At first I was using daemon processes instead of sentinels, but sentinels are cleaner, so I switched to that. I just forgot to move `self.daemon = True` line.

Answer (score 1):

Would you be happy with a very mild fork of `multiprocessing` that can make this pattern work?  If so, you only have to look down a little further in the link you referred to in your question: [Can't pickle <type 'instancemethod'> when using python's multiprocessing Pool.map()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816958/cant-pickle-type-instancemethod-when-using-pythons-multiprocessing-pool-ma?lq=1).

As `pathos.multiprocessing` has a `Pool` that can pickle instance methods in a very clean way, you can just work as you would code in serial python… and *it just works*… even directly from the interpreter.

```
>>> from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool as Pool
>>> from Queue import Queue
>>> from time import sleep
>>> 
>>> class Agent:
...   def __init__(self):
...     self.pool = Pool()
...     self.queue = Queue()
...   def produce(self, f, *args, **kwds):
...     self.queue.put(self.pool.apipe(f, *args, **kwds))
...   def do_some_work(self):
...     self.produce(self.foo, waka='waka')
...   def do_some_other_work(self):
...     self.produce(self.bar, humana='humana')
...   def foo(self, **kwds):
...     sleep(5)
...     return 'this is a foo'
...   def bar(self, **kwds):
...     sleep(10) 
...     return 'this is a bar'
...   def get_results(self):
...     res = []
...     while not self.queue.empty():
...       res.append(self.queue.get().get())
...     return res
... 
>>> agents = [Agent() for i in range(50)]
>>> for agent in agents:
...   agent.do_some_work()
...   agent.do_some_other_work()
... 
>>> for agent in agents:
...   print(agent.get_results())
... 
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
['this is a foo', 'this is a bar']
>>>
```

Get `pathos` here: https://github.com/uqfoundation