# Python multiprocessing: cPickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'instancemethod'>

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I am trying to use python `multiprocessing` module to process a large set of urls for which I am creating worker processes using a `multiprocessing.Pool` object as shown below.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, TimeoutError, cpu_count

class MyClass:
    def square(self, x):
        return x*x

    @staticmethod
    def getNumbers():
        return range(10)

    def calculate(self):
        pool = Pool(processes=min(cpu_count(),8))
        results = [pool.apply(self.square,(i,)) for i in self.getNumbers()]
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        for result in results:
            print result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    instance = MyClass()
    instance.calculate()
```

However the above piece of code results in a pickling error as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "multi.py", line 24, in <module>
    instance.calculate()
  File "multi.py", line 15, in calculate
    results = [pool.apply(self.square,(i,)) for i in self.getNumbers()]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 244, in apply
    return self.apply_async(func, args, kwds).get()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 558, in get
    raise self._value
cPickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'instancemethod'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.instancemethod failed
```

**NOTE**
A similar question has been asked previously on SO by someone else but remains unanswered: [cPickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'instancemethod'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.instancemethod failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33107756/cpickle-picklingerror-cant-pickle-type-instancemethod-attribute-lookup)

**EDIT** Gave a better sample code example

Comment: Shouldn't `pool.apply(self.processURL, injectionPoint, "GET")` be `pool.apply(self.processURL, (injectionPoint, "GET"))` ?

Comment: @Shaung yeah, sorry made a mistake while copying and editing code here. Corrected now. Thanks for noticing :)

Comment: I found a "trick" on the following link, but I guess this is a poor hack, not sure. Please help me understand whats the problem with pickling `<type 'instancemethod'>:` in `multiprocessing` and how to handle that correctly for use within class instance methods.

Trick mentioned on this link:
http://www.rueckstiess.net/research/snippets/show/ca1d7d90

Answer (score 3):

You cannot pickle instance methods using the multiprocessing package in python. Instance methods aren't listed in the pickling [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled).

If you don't mind using an external library, you can look at [multiprocess](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/multiprocess), which is a drop-in replacement for python's multiprocessing. 
To make use of the library, you would do the following:

- `pip install multiprocess`
- replace`from multiprocessing import Pool, TimeoutError, cpu_count` with
  `from multiprocess import Pool, TimeoutError, cpu_count`

I have tested your example on my machine and it actually executes using multiprocess.

Comment: This worked instantly. Thanks