# cPickle error with pathos multiprocessing?

Tags: python-2.7, multiprocessing, pickle, pathos

I'm trying to use multiprocessing to speed up pandas excel reading. However when I use multiprocessing I'm getting the error 
**cPickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle : attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed**

when I try to run the following:
import dill
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessPool

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.files = glob.glob(\*)

    def read_file(self, filename):
        return pd.read_excel(filename)

    def file_data(self):
        pool = ProcessPool(9)
        file_list = [filename for filename in self.files]
        df_list = pool.map(A().read_file, file_list)
        combined_df = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)
```

Isn't pathos.multiprocessing designed to fix this issue? Am I overlooking something here?

Edit: 
The pathos author says that it is not a duplicate. glob.glob(/*) is me not giving my directory where the files are stored, as it's unrelated to the problem.

```
File "c:\users\zky3sse\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pathos-0.2.0-py2.7.egg\
pathos\multiprocessing.py", line 136, in map
return _pool.map(star(f), zip(*args)) # chunksize
  File "C:\Users\ZKY3SSE\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 251, in map
return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\Users\ZKY3SSE\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 567, in get
raise self._value
```

Comment: What is `glob.glob(\*)` supposed to do? That's not valid Python.

Comment: And you can't send bound methods into a pool. Send functions only.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I think you are wrong and this question is not a duplicate.  I'm the `pathos` author, and @boson is asking about pickling with `pathos`, which can send bound methods through a pool.

Comment: @boson: it looks like you are on windows, and if you didn't use `freeze_support`, you can get this cryptic error.  Sorry I can't answer more extensively in the comments.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21345273/2379433

Comment: @MikeMcKerns thanks for the info; reduped to their previous question.