# multiprocessing.apply_async(myfunc, ...) within a class doesn't seem to call myfunc

Tags: python, asynchronous, multiprocessing

```
import multiprocessing


class multiprocessing_issue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.test_mp()

    def print_test(self):
        print "TEST TEST TEST"

    def test_mp(self):
        p = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
        p.apply_async(self.print_test, args=())
        print "finished"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing_issue()
```

I've set up a simple test above, create a class, call `apply_async` with a function that should print `"TEST TEST TEST"`. When I run this I see `"finished"` printed, but it never prints `"TEST TEST TEST"` as expected.

Can anyone see the error in this simple test case? I've set it up to reproduce the way I'm using it in my code.

Python 2.7 on Ubuntu

Comment: What version of Python is this? And what OS?

Comment: On 2.7 and on Windows I also get "Finished" followed by a heavy crash of all the processes with `ImportError: No module named tmp0jekzi` probably due to the `pool` not being shielded by `if __name__ == '__main__'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify `test_mp` as follows:

```
def test_mp(self):
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
    r = p.apply_async(self.print_test, args=())
    print r.get()
```

and the answer will be more clear.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 18, in <module>
    multiprocessing_issue()
  File "test.py", line 6, in __init__
    self.test_mp()
  File "test.py", line 14, in test_mp
    print r.get()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 567, in get
    raise self._value
cPickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'instancemethod'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.instancemethod failed
```

Instance methods [cannot be serialized](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled) that easily. What the Pickle protocol does when serialising a function is simply turning it into a string.

```
In [1]: dumps(function)
Out[1]: 'c__main__\nfunction\np0\n.'
```

For a child process would be quite hard to find the right object your instance method is referring to due to separate process address spaces.

Modules such as [dill](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dill) are doing a better job than Pickle. Yet I would discourage you from mixing concurrency and OOP as the logic gets confusing pretty easily.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, it's a problem moving the class reference between processes, if I define the method at the module level instead of the class level everything works.

```
import multiprocessing


class multiprocessing_issue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.test_mp()

    def test_mp(self):
        p = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
        r = p.apply_async(mptest, args=())
        r.get()
        print "finished"


def mptest():
    print "TEST TEST TEST"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing_issue()
```

Comment: Eh, my last comment didn't make sense, I missed `self.test_mp()`. I guess I'm not used to people using classes like this. It doesn't really make sense to me that you would create a class for this and then define `__init__` just to run a class method. But I see your main tag is `java` :P

Comment: It doesn't make so much sense, you're right, well, it did when I started using threading for parallelism, but I'm trying to deal with threading issues by switching to multiprocessing without rewriting all my code. Gotcha's within gotcha's.

Comment: For future reference on this question this is a useful and related article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816958/cant-pickle-type-instancemethod-when-using-pythons-multiprocessing-pool-ma

Comment: I would to know why it only when you call  r.get(). The function doesn't necessarily return anything.

Comment: There's no return statement on `mptest` so the default return value is `None`. I'm not sure I understand the question. @DavidOkwii

Comment: Sorry, I meant that calling the apply_async() only worked when followed it up with a call to r.get(). I am using apply_async(send_emails, args) to call a function that sends emails to users, so I don't need to block or return anything. However, it doesn't work unless I call the get method like  apply_async(send_emails, args).get(). I don't understand why!

Comment: FYI you can also define the method as a `@staticmethod` inside the class it would also work