# Python multiprocessing.Pool.apply_async() not executing class function

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, python-class

In a custom class I have the following code:

```
class CustomClass():
    
    triggerQueue: multiprocessing.Queue

    def __init__(self):
        
        self.triggerQueue = multiprocessing.Queue()

    def poolFunc(queueString):
        
        print(queueString)

    def listenerFunc(self):

        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(5)

        while True:
            try:
                queueString = self.triggerQueue.get_nowait()
                pool.apply_async(func=self.poolFunc, args=(queueString,))

            except queue.Empty:
                break
```

What I intend to do is:

- add a trigger to the queue (not implemented in this snippet) -> works as intended
- run an endless loop within the listenerFunc that reads all triggers from the queue (if any are found) -> works as intended
- pass trigger to poolFunc which is to be executed asynchronosly -> not working

It works as soon as I source my poolFun() outside of the class like

```
def poolFunc(queueString):
        
    print(queueString)

class CustomClass():
    [...]
```

But why is that so? Do I have to pass the self argument somehow? Is it impossible to perform it this way in general?

Thank you for any hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems going on here.

1. Your instance method, `poolFunc`, is missing a `self` parameter.
2. You are never properly terminating the Pool. You should take advantage of the fact that a multiprocessing.Pool object is a context manager.
3. You're calling `apply_async`, but you're never waiting for the results. Read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult): you need to call the `get` method on the `AsyncResult` object to receive the result; if you don't do this before your program exits your `poolFunc` function may never run.
4. By making the Queue object part of your class, you won't be able to pass instance methods to workers.

We can fix all of the above like this:

```
import multiprocessing
import queue

triggerQueue = multiprocessing.Queue()


class CustomClass:
    def poolFunc(self, queueString):
        print(queueString)

    def listenerFunc(self):

        results = []

        with multiprocessing.Pool(5) as pool:
            while True:
                try:
                    queueString = triggerQueue.get_nowait()
                    results.append(pool.apply_async(self.poolFunc, (queueString,)))
                except queue.Empty:
                    break

            for res in results:
                print(res.get())


c = CustomClass()

for i in range(10):
    triggerQueue.put(f"testval{i}")

c.listenerFunc()
```

You can, as you mention, also replace your instance method with a static method, in which case we can keep triggerQueue as part of the class:

```
import multiprocessing
import queue


class CustomClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.triggerQueue = multiprocessing.Queue()

    @staticmethod
    def poolFunc(queueString):
        print(queueString)

    def listenerFunc(self):

        results = []

        with multiprocessing.Pool(5) as pool:
            while True:
                try:
                    queueString = self.triggerQueue.get_nowait()
                    results.append(pool.apply_async(self.poolFunc, (queueString,)))
                except queue.Empty:
                    break

            for r in results:
                print(r.get())


c = CustomClass()

for i in range(10):
    c.triggerQueue.put(f"testval{i}")

c.listenerFunc()
```

But we still need to reap the `pool_async` results.

Comment: Thank you! Tested both methods and they work as intended

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found an answer and a workaround:

the answer is based the anser of noxdafox to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43640074/multiprocessing-apply-asyncmyfunc-within-a-class-doesnt-seem-to-call-myf) question.

> Instance methods cannot be serialized that easily. What the Pickle protocol does when serialising a function is simply turning it into a string.

> For a child process would be quite hard to find the right object your instance method is referring to due to separate process address spaces.

A functioning workaround is to declare the poolFunc() as static function like

```
@staticmethod
def poolFunc(queueString):
    
    print(queueString)
```