# PicklingError in Python multi-processing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

As a simple example, when I run the following code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

class foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0

    def g(self, x):
        return x + self.a

    def bar(self):
        def f(x):
            return self.g(x)**2

        # Compute [f(x) for x in range(1000)] in parallel
        pool = Pool()
        res = pool.map(f, range(1000))
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

        return res

res = foo().bar()
```

I get the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PicklingError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-cbbd76310b60> in <module>()
     19         return res
     20
---> 21 res = foo().bar()

<ipython-input-7-cbbd76310b60> in bar(self)
     13         # Compute [f(x) for x in range(1000)] in parallel
     14         pool = Pool()
---> 15         res = pool.map(f, range(1000))
     16         pool.close()
     17         pool.join()

/Users/jiaseny/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.pyc in map(self, func, iterable, chunksize)
    251         '''
    252         assert self._state == RUN
--> 253         return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
    254
    255     def imap(self, func, iterable, chunksize=1):

/Users/jiaseny/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.pyc in get(self, timeout)
    570             return self._value
    571         else:
--> 572             raise self._value
    573
    574     def _set(self, i, obj):

PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed
```

I believe it's because the function `f` called `self.g` during computation.
Is there any way to resolve this issue?

One work-around would be to make `g` a local function inside `bar`, but in more complicated classes this would be impractical since `g` would probably also contain some other function `self.h` and so on...

Comment: actually just the fact that you defined the function inside another function is enough, this is almost an exact duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816958/cant-pickle-type-instancemethod-when-using-multiprocessing-pool-map

Comment: Thanks! I solved the issue using pathos.multiprocessing.