# Can't pickle local object

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing, pathos

I would like to use multiprocess package for example in this [code](https://repl.it/@kabamaru/CoalaTree). 
I've tried to call the function `create_new_population` and distribute the data to 8 processors, but when I do I get pickle error.

Normally the function would run like this: `self.create_new_population(self.pop_size)`

I try to distribute the work like this:

```
f= self.create_new_population
pop = self.pop_size/8
self.current_generation = [pool.apply_async(f, pop) for _ in range(8)]
```

I get ***`Can't pickle local object 'exhaust.__init__.<locals>.tour_select'`***
or ***`PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied`***

I've read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816958/cant-pickle-type-instancemethod-when-using-multiprocessing-pool-map) carefully and also tried to bypass the error using [an approach from Steven Bethard](https://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/552476-why-cant-you-pickle-instancemethods) to allow method pickling/unpickling via copyreg:

```
def _pickle_method(method)
def _unpickle_method(func_name, obj, cls)
```

I also tried to use `pathos` package without any luck.
I've know that the code should be called under 
`if __name__ == '__main__':` block, but I would like to know if this can be done with minimum possible changes in the code.

Comment: Hi I'm the `pathos` author.  You don't need to follow the advice about picking instance methods, `dill` can pickle instance methods no problem... and `pathos` uses `dill`. You also don't need to run your code under `__main__`, however it typically does help, especially if you are on windows (and if you are, then use `freeze_support`).  So your question is... can your code be modified to run under `__main__` with little changes -- the answer is yes.  Just (a) add a wrapper function called from `__main__` that calls your code, and (b) if possible, (but not necessary) build `Pool` in `__main__`.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to build a genetic algorithm that leverages parallel computing.  There is one in `mystic`, if you are interested.  It uses `pathos`, and has over 10 years of support for massively parallel computations.  https://github.com/uqfoundation/mystic -- Note: I'm also the `mystic` author.

Comment: @MikeMcKerns .Thank you very much Mike, I will implement (a) and (b) suggestions in my code. Meanwhile I've updated python in my pc to 3.6.5 and pathos run! But the fact that is 5 times slower than the serial version puzzles me.

Comment: There's overhead in setting up the parallel computation. With `multiprocessing`, it has to spin up N instances of python and also serialize the objects.  Parallel doesn't always mean faster... it gets faster when your code is more computationally expensive than the overhead of going to parallel.  You might want to try `pathos.pools.ThreadPool`.