# Keeping boto3 session alive in multiprocessing pool

Tags: python, multiprocessing, boto3

I'm trying to delete a lot of files in s3. I am planning on using a `multiprocessing.Pool` for doing all these deletes, but I'm not sure how to keep the `s3.client` alive between jobs. I'm wanting to do something like

```
import boto3
import multiprocessing as mp

def work(key):
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    s3_client.delete_object(Bucket='bucket', Key=key)

with mp.Pool() as pool:
    pool.map(work, lazy_iterator_of_billion_keys)
```

But the problem with this is that a significant amount of time is spent doing the `s3_client = boto3.client('s3')` at the start of each job. [The documentation says to make a new resource instance for each process](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/resources.html?highlight=multithreading#multithreading-multiprocessing) so I need a way to make a s3 client for each process.

Is there any way to make a persistent s3 client for each process in the pool or cache the clients?

Also, I am planning on optimizing the deletes by sending batches of keys and using `s3_client.delete_objects`, but showed `s3_client.delete_object` in my example for simplicity.

Comment: Does the following question and its answers help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51310604/how-to-use-boto3-client-with-python-multiprocessing

Comment: No, that question is more about passing objects into a multiprocess pool.

Answer (score 4):

Check this snippet from the [RealPython](https://realpython.com/python-concurrency/#multiprocessing-version) concurrency tutorial. They create a single request Session for each process since you cannot share resources because each pool has its own memory space. Instead, they create a global session object to initialize the multiprocessing pool, otherwise, each time the function is called it would instantiate a Session object which is an expensive operation.

So, following that logic, you could instantiate the boto3 client that way and you would only create one client per process.

```py
import requests
import multiprocessing
import time

session = None


def set_global_session():
    global session
    if not session:
        session = requests.Session()


def download_site(url):
    with session.get(url) as response:
        name = multiprocessing.current_process().name
        print(f"{name}:Read {len(response.content)} from {url}")


def download_all_sites(sites):
    with multiprocessing.Pool(initializer=set_global_session) as pool:
        pool.map(download_site, sites)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sites = [
        "https://www.jython.org",
        "http://olympus.realpython.org/dice",
    ] * 80
    start_time = time.time()
    download_all_sites(sites)
    duration = time.time() - start_time
    print(f"Downloaded {len(sites)} in {duration} seconds")
```

Comment: I like the idea of this, but I avoid using `global` and top level variables whenever possible. I benchmarked this method in [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57874665/4498684) to show it's still fast though.

Comment: not entirely sure what's going on here, or how it helps. Why is this different than just creating a global session object outside the function? When would the global session variable be set to None during runtime?

Answer (score 2):

I ended up solving this using `functools.lru_cache` and a helper function for getting the s3 client. An LRU cache will stay consistent in a process, so it will preserve the connection. The helper function looks like

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache()
def s3_client():
    return boto3.client('s3')
```

and then that is called in my `work` function like

```
def work(key):
    s3_client = s3_client()
    s3_client.delete_object(Bucket='bucket', Key=key)
```

I was able to test this and benchmark it in the following way:

```
import os
from time import time

def benchmark(key):
    t1 = time()
    s3 = get_s3()
    print(f'[{os.getpid()}] [{s3.head_object(Bucket='bucket', Key=key)}] :: Total time: {time() - t1} s')

with mp.Pool() as p:
    p.map(benchmark, big_list_of_keys)
```

And this result showed that the first function call for each pid would take about 0.5 seconds and then subsequent calls for the same pid would take about 2e-6 seconds. This was proof enough to me that the client connection was being cached and working as I expected.

Interestingly, if I don't have `@lru_cache()` on `s3_client()` then subsequent calls would take about 0.005 seconds, so there must be some internal caching that happens automatically with boto3 that I wasn't aware of.

And for testing purposes, I benchmarked [Milton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57872924/4498684) in the following way

```
s3 = None

def set_global_session():
    global s3
    if not s3:
        s3 = boto3.client('s3')

with mp.Pool(initializer=set_global_session) as p:
    p.map(benchmark, big_list_of_keys)
```

And this also had averaging 3e-6 seconds per job, so pretty much the same as using `functools.lru_cache` on a helper function.