# multiprocessing & pickling bound objects

Tags: python, multiprocessing, jupyter-notebook

I know that there are differences with how python's `multiprocessing` on Mac and Windows; for example:

- https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/10894
- https://bugs.python.org/issue25053

these posts seem to imply that the issue is to do with how functions that are not in their own module are pickled, although [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1816969/889604) is a little more specific, and says that the issue is with *bound methods*.

On Windows, I can start a Jupyter Notebook, and pickle a function I define there:

```
import pickle
def test(): return None
pickle.dumps(test)
```

and returns `b'\x80\x03c__main__\nt\nq\x00.'`
(as expected, this also works directly in a standard interactive python session).

However, wrapping this within a multiprocessor call does, as expected, generate an error (in both a notebook and terminal):

```
> import multiprocessing as mp
> def test(): return None
> p = mp.Pool(processes=2)
> p.map(test, range(2))
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'test' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
```

This does work in an interactive session on a Mac (although the function defined interactively needs an argument to prevent an error of `TypeError: test() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given.`)

This must mean I haven't got a total grasp on what multiprocessing is doing - I thought it was just pickling the objects, but given I can pickle objects defined in a notebook, multiprocessing must be doing more than this. Can anybody fill in the gaps in my understanding?!

Comment: The reason you're getting the # args error is because `map` applies each element in `range(2)` to `test`--essentially calling `test(0)`, then `test(1)`.

Comment: Yeh, I'd worked that out :) if you've got any idea about the other issue I'll be highly grateful!