# Python multiprocessing: calling methods and passing objects in asynchronous calls

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, asynchronous, multiprocessing

I am trying to accomplish two things with `apply_async` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult) call:

(i) Call a class method

(ii) Pass an object as param

I have the following baseline code so far:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

class myClass():
  def __init__(self, id):
    self.id = id
    self.val = 1.0
    self.pool = None

  def callback(self, obj):
    self.val = obj.val

def foo(new_val):  # foo is outside myClass
    print ('foo passed with', new_val)
    c1.val = new_val
    return c1

if __name__ == '__main__':
  c1 = myClass('c1')
  c1.pool = mp.Pool(processes=1)
  c1.pool.apply_async(foo, args=(2.0, ), callback=c1.callback).wait()  
  c1.pool.close()
  c1.pool.join()
  print ('c1.val:', c1.val)  # should display 'c1 val: 2.0'
```

Output:

```
foo passed with 2.0
c1.val: 2.0
```

When I try to accomplish (i) with the code below, I don't get the same output as above.

```
class myClass():
  def __init__(self, id):
    self.id = id
    self.val = 1.0
    self.pool = None

  def callback(self, obj):
    self.val = obj.val

  def foo(self, new_val):  # foo is inside myClass
      print ('foo passed with', new_val)
      self.val = new_val
      return self

if __name__ == '__main__':
  c1 = myClass('c1')
  c1.pool = mp.Pool(processes=1)
  c1.pool.apply_async(c1.foo, args=(2.0, ), callback=c1.callback).wait()  
  c1.pool.close()
  c1.pool.join()
  print ('c1.val:', c1.val)  # should display 'c1 val: 2.0'
```

Output:

```
c1.val: 1.0
```

Similarly, when I try to accomplish (ii), `foo` does not get called again.

```
class myClass():
  def __init__(self, id):
    self.id = id
    self.val = 1.0
    self.pool = None

  def callback(self, obj):
    self.val = obj.val

def foo(obj, new_val):  # foo is outside myClass
    print ('foo passed with', new_val)
    obj.val = new_val
    return obj

if __name__ == '__main__':
  c1 = myClass('c1')
  c1.pool = mp.Pool(processes=1)
  c1.pool.apply_async(foo, args=(c1, 2.0, ), callback=c1.callback).wait()  
  c1.pool.close()
  c1.pool.join()
  print ('c1.val:', c1.val)  # should display 'c1 val: 2.0'
```

Output:

```
c1.val: 1.0
```

Any idea what needs to be changed in the code above to accomplish (i) and (ii)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call was not completed without raising an exception. You can check that with the [`multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult.successful`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult.successful) method:

```
import multiprocessing as mp


class myClass():
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
        self.val = 1.0
        self.pool = None

    def callback(self, obj):
        self.val = obj.val

    def foo(self, new_val):
        print ('foo passed with', new_val)
        self.val = new_val
        return self

if __name__ == '__main__':
    c1 = myClass('c1')
    c1.pool = mp.Pool(processes=1)
    async_result = c1.pool.apply_async(c1.foo, args=(2.0, ), callback=c1.callback)
    async_result.wait()
    print(async_result.successful())  # this is printing False!!!
    c1.pool.close()
    c1.pool.join()
    print ('c1.val:', c1.val)
```

Now you can define an `error_callback` to see what's going on:

```
...
async_result = c1.pool.apply_async(c1.foo, args=(2.0, ), callback=c1.callback, error_callback=lambda x: print(x))
...
```

This is the error being printed by this function:

```
pool objects cannot be passed between processes or pickled
```

On [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816958/cant-pickle-type-instancemethod-when-using-multiprocessing-pool-map) you can find more info on why this is happening. The problem is that the `multiprocessing` code has to pickle the things that it sends to the sub-processes it has started, and the pickler doesn't do instance-methods.

Comment: *"pickler doesn't do instance-methods"*. This is not a problem in python 3+, instance methods are very much picklable (in fact, they are never even being pickled, only their relevant name is). The error is instead happening because of the line `c1.pool = mp.Pool(processes=1)`. Storing the pool (an unpicklable object) as an instance attribute is what's causing the error because all instance attributes are implicitly pickled if the target function is an instance method or the arguments include the instance itself. Therefore, not storing the pool inside the instance would solve the issue.